# Classificação de complexidade de algoritmo O(log n)

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Ao analisar o seguinte código:

```
int sumArray(int arr[], int n){
    int soma = 0; // O(1)
    int i = 0; // O(1)
    while( i < n){ // O(n)
       for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){ // O(n)

          soma += arr[i]+arr[j]; // O(1)
       }
       i++ // O(1)
    }
    return soma; // O(1)


}
```

Cheguei a conclusão que a complexidade é O(n^2), pois ignoram-se as constantes e multiplica O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2)

Assumi que o while tinha complexidade O(n) pois fui instruído que qualquer 'for' e 'while' tem complexidades O(n).

Agora, estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade em compreender como o seguinte algorítimo tem uma complexidade O(log n)

```
int n = 8; //O(1)

while(n>1){ // O(log n)

    n = n/2; // O(1)

}
```

Como a estrutura 'while' tem complexidade O(log n)?

Comment: A quantidade de vezes que o loop roda é mais próximo de logN do que de N. No caso do seu código, o loop roda 3 vezes. Se N for 1024, vai rodar só 10 vezes, se for 4 bilhões, vai rodar 30 vezes. Para entender melhor, leia [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42568759) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258)